# Web scraping with casperjs returns error

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am trying to scrape a website using the casperjs library. I am not able to get it to progress past a certain page, as it constantly redirects and loops back to the page I am on, despite correctly entering for the form.

```
casper.then(function(){
    // skipped for brevity
    // form details entered

    this.click("#login-button"); // submit form with input button
}
```

and then when I go the next main login page:

```
casper.then(function(){
    capture(); // capture screenshot
}
```

all it returns is the page I am still currently on. What is going on?

Comment: This is a perfectly fine selector. Are there more than one `id="login-button"` elements on the page? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors.

Answer (score 0):

The `click` function in casperjs doesn't use that sort of selector, but instead uses new CSS3 ones. You said that the form was an input element? If that's the case then you can use the selector `input[id='login-button']` instead.

```
casper.then(function(){
    // skipped for brevity
    // form details entered

    this.click("input[id='login-button']"); // submit form with input button
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! Does the syntax of a CSS3 selector follow `element[attr='value']` then?

Comment: Indeed it does. You can find out more info in the [docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/). Also, welcome to the community! Don't forget to accept the answer once 15 minutes has passed.

Comment: `#login-button` is a perfectly fine CSS selector. The reason it was necessary to use an CSS attribute selector was probably because the page is broken and uses the ID multiple times. (This answer was prepared, right?)